complex Gamma function represented as integral on complex semi-line.
Let $s \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfying $|s| \geq 1$ and $|\text{arg}(s)| \leq \pi - \delta$.
The notes I am reading claim that Cauchy's residue theorem can be used to write $$\Gamma(s) = \frac{1}{s}\int_{L}e^{-z}z^sdz,$$ where $L$ is the semiline $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : z = \lambda s, \lambda \geq 0\}$ traversed from $0$ to $\infty$.
I'm struggling to verify this claim.
Here is my attempt:
I tried to set up a contour to relate the semiline $L$ to the positive real axis as follows. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be small and $R > 0$ be large. Let $\theta = \text{arg}(s)$, $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi - \delta$.
Let the contour $\gamma$ be the union of four contours $\gamma = \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 + \gamma_3 + \gamma_4$. Where $$\gamma_1 = \{z \in \mathbb{R} : \epsilon \leq z \leq R\}.$$ $$\gamma_2 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : z = Re^{i\alpha}, 0 \leq \alpha \leq \theta\}.$$ $$\gamma_3 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : z = re^{i\theta}, \epsilon \leq r \leq R\}.$$ $$\gamma_4 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : z = \epsilon e^{i\alpha}, 0 \leq \alpha \leq \theta\}.$$
I tried to analyze the integral $\int_L e^{-z}z^sdz$ on the contour $\gamma_4$ to show it goes to zero as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ but I was only able to get $$\int_{\gamma_4} e^{-z}z^sdz \ll \epsilon^{\text{Re}(s)+1}\theta$$ but if $\text{Re}(s)$ is very negative, then this blows up. So I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.
